# Can not change shadow on Toolbar with AppBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have Toolbar inside AppBarLayout and CoordinatorLayout. The designer wants to change elevation shadow to 1dp, but I can not change it for some reason.

If I add this on AppBarLayout then it removes shadow:

```
app:elevation="2dp"
```

If I remove it, then I have default 4dp elevation shadow.

I want to change it to 1dp.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityCategoryAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    app:elevation="@dimen/elevationSize"
    >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/activityCategoryToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityCategorySrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activityCategoryRvPosts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Remove this : `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` and then try.

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: what's your support_lib_version?

Comment: I am using 27.1.1

Comment: show this @style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `AppBarLayout` code to:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

And add `appbar_always_elevated.xml` in `animator` directory with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                        android:valueTo="1dp"
                        android:valueType="floatType"
                        android:duration="1"/>
    </item>

</selector>
```

It should work now.

You can change `android:valueTo` value to set shadow. Also, `app:elevation` is not working on new APIs.

> @deprecated target elevation **is now deprecated.**
>
> **Source:** https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/master/sdk/sources/android-25/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F

Comment: I have tried this, but still does not work. I really do not know why.